# How to use erc20 custom token on multiple chains?

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, polygon, erc20, erc721

If erc20 tokens are deplopyed  on ethereum and dapp is on polygon, we cannot use the following code

```
IERC20 token = IERC20(add);
```

So to use my tokens on polygon dapp as a payment, I can use bridging. If I send my tokens to polygon through bridging, bridging service will create a new contract on my behalf and I can use the new contract's address in my polygon dapp's contract file. (Is my concept on bridging right?)

But I feel like this is a little problematic approach and gas fees is also big issue here. So I was thinking if it is possible to deploy two contracts for my same tokens - one on ethereum and the other on polygon. Is it a bad practice? Will it create a coin inconsistency?

Please help. I am looking for an appropriate answer for a long time. Couldn't have found  any yet.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it a bad practice?

Yes.

> Will it create a coin inconsistency?

Yes.

Comment: So is bridging the only way to do transfer my erc20 custom tokens from ethereum to polygon? And is my concept about bridging right? @Mikko Ohtamaa

Comment: Yes, it is right.